# How can I use a foreach loop to build json objects and call jquery functions in razor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to take a list of objects and iterate through the list and build a json object and call a jquery function in a foreach loop of razor.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.CoordinatesObj) {
        var pinpoint = { "top": item.Top,
                "left": item.Left,
                "width": item.Width,
                "height": item.Height
            };
       $("#toPinpoint").mapImage.addPinpointExt(pinpoint);
}
```

I want to be able to do this so it dynamically builds this pinpoint object and is used to pass through my addPinpointExt function.  the Model.CoordinatesObj is a List of objects.  Is this even possible this way?  If not what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the for loop in an MVC action and then call it using $.ajax()

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/Home/NewAction/id", type: "POST", 
   error : function(req,status,errorObj) { /* handle error */ }, 
   success: function(result) {
        var pinpoint = result;
        $("#toPinpoint").mapImage.addPinpointExt(pinpoint);
   }
});
```

use Razor for generating HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("p")ToArray()
```

Creates an array for you holding value of every html element ('p' paragraph in example)
Alternatively you can use each() Jquery function to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mix server-side code with plain text (Javascript/JSON in your case), you can wrap the plain text in a `<text>` tag:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.CoordinatesObj) {
    <text>
    var pinpoint = { "top": @item.Top,
            "left": @item.Left,
            "width": @item.Width,
            "height": @item.Height
        };
    $("#toPinpoint").mapImage.addPinpointExt(pinpoint);
    </text>
}
```

Notice you were also missing the `@` in front of the server-side variables.

Phil Haack has a nice reference page on [Razor syntax](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/).